# document.getElementById.innerHTML does not write anything ..?

Tags: javascript, html

#### My Problem:

`document.getElementById("values").innerHTML` does not write anything. If I try to do `document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = "stuff";` (just with a String) - nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong here?

#### HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="save_entry();return false;">
  <label for="i_km">Kilometer: <input type="text" name="km" id="i_km"></label><br>
  <label for="i_fuel">Sprit: <input type="text" name="fuel" id="i_fuel"></label><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<div id="values"></div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
function save_entry() {
  var anzahl = localStorage.length/2;
  var nameKeyKm = "k" + anzahl;
  localStorage.setItem(nameKeyKm,document.forms[0]["km"].value);
  var nameKeyF = "F" + anzahl;
  localStorage.setItem(nameKeyF,document.forms[0]["fuel"].value);
  document.write("Entry saved!")
}

function show_entry() {
  document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = "<table><th>Kilometers</th><th>Tanked</th>";
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length/2; i++) {
    alert("d");
    var temp_km = "k"+i;
    var temp_f = "F"+i;
    document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = "<tr>";
    document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = "<td>"+localStorage.getItem(temp_km)+"</td>";
    document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = "<td>"+localStorage.getItem(temp_f)+"</td>";
    document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = "</tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = "</table>";
}
show_entry();
```

Answer (score 1):

This does work!

```
function show_entry(){
    var content = '';
    content = content + '<table><th>Kilometer</th><th>Getankt</th>';

    for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length/2; i++)
    {
    var temp_km = "k"+i;
    var temp_f = "F"+i;
    content = content + "<tr>";
    content = content + "<td>"+localStorage.getItem(temp_km)+"</td>";
    content = content + "<td>"+localStorage.getItem(temp_f)+"</td>";
    content = content + "</tr>";
    }
    content = content + "</table>";

    document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = content;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you do

```
document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = "...";
```

you will replace the html inside the div with ID 'values'
So calling it multiple times with different values doesn't make sense.

You would either call it once and setting the whole innerHTML at once, like this

```
document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = "<tr><td>....etc...</td></tr>";
```

If you would call innerHTML sequentially you would do it as follows (which is just how to append any string in javascript), but in the comments below I just learned this should **not be done like this:**

```
document.getElementById("values").innerHTML += "<tr>";
document.getElementById("values").innerHTML += "<td>"+localStorage.getItem(temp_km)+"</td>";
document.getElementById("values").innerHTML += "<td>"+localStorage.getItem(temp_f)+"</td>";
document.getElementById("values").innerHTML += "</tr>";
```

Comment: Don't "append" HTML like that. It causes the existing DOM to be serialised to HTML, edited, then a new DOM is generated from the result and assigned back. You *cannot* put partial elements in by appending them to `innerHTML` sequentially.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, that's interesting. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

`innherHTML` is an attribute, so everytime you write `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = '...'` you are actually changing the value of `innerHTML` to that thing, not concatenating it.

So writing `document.getElementById("values").innerHTML = "<table><th>Kilometers</th><th>Tanked</th>"'` changes the value of `innerHTML` to `"<table><th>Kilometers</th><th>Tanked</th>"'`, and, afterwards, you replaced this value for `<tr>`, then for `<td>...</td>` and so on...

You clearly want to create a table. Therefore, you should be concatenating the strings, using `+=`, like this:

```
function show_entry() {
    document
        .getElementById("values")
        .innerHTML = "<table><th>Kilometers</th><th>Tanked</th>";

    for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length/2; i++)
    {
        var temp_km = "k"+i;
        var temp_f = "F"+i;

        document.getElementById("values").innerHTML += "<tr>";
        document.getElementById("values").innerHTML += "<td>"+localStorage.getItem(temp_km)+"</td>";
        document.getElementById("values").innerHTML += "<td>"+localStorage.getItem(temp_f)+"</td>";
        document.getElementById("values").innerHTML += "</tr>";
    }

    document.getElementById("values").innerHTML += "</table>";
}

show_entry();
```